# Apply color palette to picture

Tags: c#, compression, color-palette

I need to make a compression algorithm for `.img` binary image file. The image is lets say 512x512. I am using `BinaryReader` to get the binary file pixel by pixel and i am saving it in `short[,]`. It goes something like this:

```
br1 = new BinaryReader(File.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open));
short[,] num = new short[512, 512];
for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 512; j++)
    {
         num[i, j] = (short)br1.ReadInt16();
    }
```

What I do not understand is how am i going to convert values which I get between [-2048,2047] into bitmap using color palette(imported .pal file).

I would really appreciate any help, suggestion, code, tutorial, whatever.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is decide which image format you want to create. there are palette based formats which hold (8 or 16 bit) pointers into palette structures and there are pixel based formats, which holds RGB values in each pixel (24bit). The latter are a little easier to create. In either case you also need to understand the meaning, in terms of color, your binary data represent. - No matter how 'hard you work' you won't be able to top the PNG or JPG compressions, though..

Comment: I want to create palette based picture and information I have is values between [-2048, 2047]. I need this part so i could show .img binary file in pictureBox before i start compressing it with my algorithm.

Comment: OK, but what do these values mean? grayscale values?

Comment: Hm, right after posting my answer I noticed that you are talking about a .pal file. So if you actually want a color file, this file would have to be mapped to the values. How large is it? do you know anything, like type & number of entries?? Note that all restrictions on the size of palettes still apply, no matter into which colors they point: no more than 256 colors are possible!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that creates a 8-bit palette based image from a datasource that gets values in the range of -2048 - +2047. Note that this is a 12 bit range of values, so actually a 16-bit palette would be necessary.

This is not supported however. Even RGB won't support them, nor will any non-specialized graphics cards.

If you need the full range of precision you will have to use external tools.

You could try to do a RGB based solution using bit-dithering to simulate 4096 gray values by varying the R, G and B values.

```
   using System.Drawing.Imaging;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   //..   

    // 8-bit grayscale
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(512,512, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

    List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();

    byte[] data = new byte[512 * 512];

    for (int y = 0; y < 512; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < 512; x++)
    {
        int v = getValue() + 2048;      // replace by your data reader!

        int r = v >> 4;                 // < here we lose 4 bits!
        int g = r;
        int b = r;
        Color c = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
        int cIndex = 0;
        if (colors.Contains(c)) cIndex = colors.IndexOf(c);
        else { colors.Add(c); cIndex = colors.Count; }

        //bmp.SetPixel(x,y,c);    // this would be used for rgb formats!
        data[y * 512 + x] = (byte) cIndex;
    }

    // prepare a locked image memory area
    var bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

    // move our data in
    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bmpData.Scan0, data.Length);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    // create the palette
    var pal = bmp.Palette;
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.Count; i++) pal.Entries[i] = colors[i];
    bmp.Palette = pal;

    // display
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Comment: Hey TaW. Thanks a lot for your answer. I managed to clear things out somehow in some way... The value from [-2048, 2047] is a index of color from the pallet which contains 4096 colours. So I will read .pal file byte by byte and I will assign each byte to R, G and B and on the beggining i'll have some index of the color i.e. first color = index 0001, second = 0002 ... And than I am planning to use setPixel function to set em up to a bitmap. Thanks for your help, a lot of things were really unclear to me but i managed to figure it out somehow.

Comment: Yes. I used Binary reader and read values from .pal file and put them in Color.FromArgb. Than I read values from .img binary file in ushort array and I got values between 0 and 4096(number of elements in the palette) and draw the picture with setPixel.